# Fast way to switch off proxy in Windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, proxy

Whenever I connect to a corporate VPN it always sets a proxy server. It is necessary for corporate WiFi but this proxy is inaccessible from internet.

This means that whenever I connect from home WiFi I cannot open any page except internal network.

The solution is to click on Start, Control Panel, Network and Internet, Internet options, Connection, Local network setting and switch off proxy checkbox there. This procedure is annoying.

I would like to have some bat script that turns it off. Could you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the Windows7 LAN proxy config from the command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/337685/how-do-i-change-the-windows7-lan-proxy-config-from-the-command-line)

Comment: It really looks like duplicate. Unfortunatelly running netsh winhttp show proxy returns same result regardless of the proxy checkbox state. Weird.

Comment: This is a better duplicate, but requires the combination of two of the  answers: [How can I change the system proxy from the command line?](http://superuser.com/q/709096). I've done this below in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How do I switch off the proxy from a batch file?

**Solution 1**:

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

Notes:

- The WinHTTP proxy settings aren't used by all applications.
- See answer [How can I change the system proxy from the command line?](https://superuser.com/a/709108) by [Oliver Salzburg](https://superuser.com/users/36744/oliver-salzburg) for more information.
- If the above solution doesn't work for your particular application Solution 2.

**Solution 2**:

1. Configure the proxy manually using the GUI, then export the registry  entries for a disabled proxy `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]`.

   See answer [How can I change the system proxy from the command line?](https://superuser.com/a/709103/337631) by [zelanix](https://superuser.com/users/293259/zelanix) for more information about this step.

   See also [How to configure client proxy server settings by using a registry file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819961) by Microsoft.
2. Write a batch file for subsequent use which:

   - Imports the registry file created as above.
   - Uses the `netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie` command.
3. Use this batch file in future to disable your proxy.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.

Comment: You're welcome. Please feel free to [accept my answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). ;)

Comment: Hmm, I found nothing. The script has no effect. Dump says: pushd winhttp
reset proxy
popd. Show proxy always says that I have direct access without proxy, even when proxy is set and turned on. Any idea?

Comment: @LeosLiterak Answer expanded to outline a second solution.

Comment: It seems that only this registry item changes: "ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001

Comment: @LeosLiterak That makes it a little easier then ;)

Comment: That is really weird. When I run this script (regedit /S proxyoff.reg
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie), chrome does not work. Then I open windows GUI and I can check that proxy is unset. Then I close this screen with Cancel and chrome starts to work!

Comment: Did you restart Chrome after running the script?

Comment: No. That would be bad as well. I do not want to loose all my work. I just want to continue.

Comment: Ok. I was just curious if a Chrome restart would fix that last remaining issue. If it does then somehow Chrome needs to be informed the proxy has changed. That could be a bug in Chrome. In any case I don't know how to fix it :/ Presumably opening/closing the GUI screen does something in addition (sends a Windows message to all open applications maybe), the question is what.

Comment: I wonder if it is worth asking a new question, with our current solution and saying it doesn't work with Chrome (although it should). That might get some more eyeballs on it.

Comment: In any case, you can surely configure Chrome to reopen all it's current tabs on a restart? Firefox has had that option for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [SETPROXY](https://bayden.com/other/) tool from the command line, or in combination with [SlickRun](https://bayden.com/SlickRun/), where I assigned some magic words using it. The author of both is the well respected original developer of [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) [Eric Lawrence](https://twitter.com/ericlaw).

Examples:

```
SETPROXY myproxyserver:8888
SETPROXY none
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refinement of some of answers already here that I plan on using for myself. It **doesn't** require any additional software, so I figured others might find it helpful.

1. Use the Windows GUI to configure your proxy settings manually as you see fit.
2. Create the following two registry scripts:

   **proxy-on.reg**

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
   "ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
   ```

   **proxy-off.reg**

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
   "ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
   ```
3. Simply run either of the following commands in the same directory as those files to enable/disable:

   ```
   regedit /S proxy-on.reg
   regedit /S proxy-off.reg
   ```

And it should toggle your system proxy settings and start working immediately. You can then expand on this further either
by writing more scripts or by toggling that registry entry on/off directly from someother app (e.g. by using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/))
with a simple keyboard shortcut.

Personally, I plan on bundling this with a script that establishes an SSH proxy in combination with updating the system
proxy settings (and then another script to terminate that connection as well as disabling the proxy system settings).

Answer (score 1):

Need to force system settings update, iexplore do it for you, the batch:

```
REM Enable-Disable System Proxy in one file
@echo off
SET home_key="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%L IN ('reg query %home_key% /v ProxyEnable' ) DO SET currentProxy=%%L
IF %currentProxy% == 0x1 goto turnoff
IF %currentProxy% == 0x0 goto turnon

:turnoff    
reg add %home_key% /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
SET proxy="Proxy disabled"
goto EOF

:turnon
reg add %home_key% /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
SET proxy="Proxy enabled"
goto EOF

:EOF
REM Restart Internet Explorer to changes take efect
start /w /b iexplore.exe
timeout 2 /nobreak
taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe
echo %proxy%
```

Answer (score 1):

For us I exported the `AutoConfigURL` key located at:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

Then use your favorite script flavor or manually delete the key to turn it off and then add the exported key to enable it again.  Basically in `Internet Properties` doing this process unchecks the `Use automatic configuration script` checkbox when the key is missing and re-checks it when you add the key back.

**To do this remotely or for another user,** you need to know the user's SID which you can find in AD or look here: `%NetworkComputerName%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

Then you can update your script or navigate manually here: `%NetworkComputerName%\HKEY_USERS\%UserSID%\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`

We have a policy to enforce proxy.  Users cannot see or change the proxy setting.